# Fiddler - Auto responder rule gives cross origin issue

Tags: cross-domain, fiddler

I have a page 'https://localhost:58525' with content from API json response. 
Api url 'http://localhost:51492/api/claimrequest/SearchNewClaimRequests'.

Fidder Autoresponder:

I added Autoresponder rule with request url pattern 'EXACT:http://localhost:51492/api/claimrequest/SearchNewClaimRequests' with response from a txt file.

Am getting below error when I try to load the page.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51492/api/claimrequest/SearchNewClaimRequests. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58525' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any way to add cross origin headers?